# Invertible matrices and Adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, adjoint-operators

I know it's basics, but I am really confused:

If $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$ and $AA^*=I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix, can we conclude that $A^*=A^{-1}$?

If not, why not?

Comment: Notably, this is the case for matrices but not for linear operators on an infinite dimensional vector space

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What would happen for linear operators on a finite or infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: Operators on a finite dimensional vector space act like matrices, so $AA^* = I$ is enough to conclude that $A^{-1} = A^*$.  However, on an infinite dimensional vector space, there exist surjective maps $A$ that fail to be injective such that $AA^* = I$ but $A^*A \neq I$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inverse is unique, if a square matrix $A$ and $B$ satisfy $$AB=I$$, then $B=A^{-1}$.

Hence $A^*=A^{-1}$